# gitlab ci .yml android

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm trying to setup gitlab CI and I can't find any information about error which I'm getting from gitlab runner. Here is .yml file :

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.3"
ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "28.0.3"

 before_script:
    - apt-get --quiet update --yes
- apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
- wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip 
   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
- unzip -q android-sdk.zip -d android-sdk-linux
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui -- all 
--filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all 
--filter platform-tools
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all 
--filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all 
--filter extra-android-m2repository
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all 
--filter extra-google-google_play_services
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all 
--filter extra-google-m2repository
- export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
- export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
- chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
stage: build
script:
  - ./gradlew assembleDebug
artifacts:
paths:
- app/build/outputs/
```

And finaly error is:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
$ wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip 
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
$ unzip -q android-sdk.zip -d android-sdk-linux
$ echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all 
--filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
************************************************************************* 
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Unrecognized argument --silent
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What should I do in this case? Can't find any information about this. 
I have tried to change path but won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just build your project (with unit tests stage) you can try simple gitlab CI script which i'm using in my project [gitlab snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1762615).

I'm not sure that this will work with build tools version 28, but you can experiment with this params.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) to setup Android SDK, instead of deprecated "android" command.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/IvanPosohov/docker/blob/master/android/Dockerfile#L20) how I setup Android SDK in my Docker file

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands and make sure you changed the compile sdk versions according to your APP, GITLAB CI configuration should be changed when the APP `gradle` configs changed.

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "26"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"

before_script:
- export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
- apt-get --quiet update --yes
- apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
- wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
- unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
- export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
- export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
- chmod +x ./gradlew
# temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
- set +o pipefail
- yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
- set -o pipefail

cache:
  paths:
  - .gradle/wrapper
  - .gradle/caches
  - android-sdk

stages:
- build

assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
  - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
```

Comment: ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "28.0.3"
ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"
Does anybody know how to convert SDK Tool Version to the number?

Answer (score 0):

For information GitLab provides up-to-date templates for various dev environment here:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/

For android project :
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Android.latest.gitlab-ci.yml